# Memory analyser tools for Qt

Tags: qt

I would like to know if any memory analyzer tools other than Valgrind are available for Qt 4. If so, then it would be quite helpful if you could tell me how to integrate them with Qt.

Comment: What exactly do you want to analyze?

Answer (score 0):

There is a page introducing several other tools on [Qt Development Network](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Profiling-and-Memory-Checking-Tools) besides Valgrind. 
I'm looking for other sites that could help you integrating to Qt.

- Very Sleepy [codersnotes.com] (Open-source CPU profiler based on sampling)
- Rational Purify [01.ibm.com] (commercial)
- Bounds Checker [microfocus.com]
- Visual Leak Detector [codeproject.com]
- AQTime [smartbear.com] (commercial) can detect memory leaks, but is mainly for profiling
- Intel Parallel Inspector [software.intel.com] (commercial)
- Luke Stackwalker [lukestackwalker.sourceforge.net] (Open-source CPU profiler based on sampling)
- Visual Studio Profiler (up to VS 2010 only in the ultimate version, VS 11 will have it in the professional version)

Comment: hey i am specifically looking for open source tools . have tried KCacheGrind and Massif Visualizer .. They do not seem to fill the purpose .. But thanks for your input and do inform if you get any information that helps to integrate these tools

Comment: i assume you are finding a tool besides Valgrind because you are using windows. or what would be the behind reasons you are searching?

Comment: No i am working on Ubuntu .Need to find and integrate a tool other than Valgrind for a professional assignment

Comment: and i cant use valgrind ... since its the default memory analyzer .. i need to compare its performance with a new tool which can be integrated with qt

Answer (score 0):

From the above options,
[Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com) is open source tools.
Since "Very Sleepy" is a stand-alone analyzer, you dont have to integrate with Qt. hope this will help you.

Comment: I have to analyse the memory leaks for Qt application ... but the problem is that i have to that using a memory analyser tool that is built in or can be integrated with qt ( Cant use a stand alone application :( ... not allowed to do  that) ...